# Typescript 4.1.5 spread operator issue

Tags: typescript

I create my own interface

```
interface MyType {
    [key :string] :boolean
}
```

And I want to use spread operator to update elements of array with new A object. Let's say:

```
aList = new Array<MyType >({['something']:true,['something2']:true});
```

and I would like to update element in this array by using spread operator like:

```
const B : MyType = {['something']: false};
this.aList = {...aList, B};
```

But I'm still getting error's , or B is adding to a aList like a new element . What could be wrong ?

- I can't just filter through aList due to the fact that B is in my scenario a $event with any type

Comment: aList is an array, not an object. use aList.push(b). but if you insist on using the spread operator, do `[...aList, B]` instead of `{...aList, B}`

Comment: @NicholasK actually i can't , i have to override exisiting item with the same key

Comment: @SimonCheng i already tried to do that , but it's returning array with just new element - example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5en3x-9b7acy?file=app%2Fbadge-overview-example.ts

Comment: @NicholasK any idea how to do it when in my scenario that B object is actually and $event with "any" type ? (that's a method to handle @output() from another component)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `aList`? are you trying to do `aList: MyType[] = [{'something':true},{'something2':true}]`?

Comment: im trying to update the value of one of the elements in the list whose key matches the element B keys so  i have list [{'something':true},{'something2':true}]  and object B {'something':false} and after {...this.aList,B} i would like to have  [{'something':false},{'something2':true}]

Comment: @Wiktor.w, I have posted the code. Please review and advise. Many thanks.

Comment: @Wiktor.w, I have updated the code and tested it. It only updated the Object which has the property.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually storing an array of `MyType` at the moment, instead you have initialized `aList` to an object which contains an array. Define it as shown below:

```
let aList: MyType[] = [{'bbb':true}, {'aaa':true}];
```

Now,

```
// find out the key that needs to be replaced
let keyToFind = '';
for (let obj in B) {
  keyToFind = obj;
}

// loop over aList to see if there is a match for `keyTofind`; 
// if found then replace that index and break
aList.forEach((obj, index) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (key === keyToFind) {
      aList[index] = B;
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@Wiktor,
Good evening. Below is the code.

```
interface MyType {
    [key: string]: boolean
}

let aList = new Array<MyType>({ ['something']: true }, { ['something2']: true });
console.log(aList);

const B: MyType = { ['something']: false };

for (let index = 0; index < aList.length; index++) {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(aList[index])} === ${JSON.stringify(B)}`);

    for (let destinationProperty in aList[index]) {
        for (let sourceProperty in B) {
            if (destinationProperty === sourceProperty) {
                aList[index] = B;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(aList);
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is basically replacing both objects in array for B . What i was looking for is to replace only value in list that key is matching B key

Comment: Got it. I am working on it. Please give me few minutes

Comment: Working fine ! , quite complicated solutions but it's working , do you have any idea why just basic {...this.aList, B} isn't working ?